# Read from excel file in C

Tags: c, excel-2007

I want to read from an excel file in C. The excel 2007 file contains about 6000 rows and 2 columns. I want to store the contents in a 2-D array in C. If there exists a C library or any other method then please let me know.

Comment: can you export it as csv?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Excel 2007 stores the data in a bunch of files, most of them in XML, all crammed together into a zip file. If you want to look at the contents, you can rename your `.xlsx` to `whatever.zip` and then open it and look at the files inside.

Assuming your Excel file just contains raw data, and all you care about is reading it (i.e., you do *not* need/want to update its contents and get Excel to open it again), reading the data is actually pretty easy. Inside the zip file, you're looking for the subdirectory `xl\worksheets\`, which will contain a number of `.xml` files, one for each worksheet from Excel (e.g., a default workbook will have three worksheets named `sheet1.xml`, `sheet2.xml` and `sheet3.xml`).

Inside of those, you're looking for the `<sheet data>` tag. Inside of that, you'll have `<row>` tags (one for each row of data), and inside of them `<c>` tags with an attribute `r=RC` where `RC` is replaced by the normal row/column notation (e.g., "A1"). The `<c>` tag will have nested `<v>` tag where you'll find the value for that cell.

I do feel obliged to add a warning though: while reading really simple data can indeed be just this easy, life can get a *lot* more complex in a hurry if you decide to do much more than reading simple rows/columns of numbers. Trying to do anything even *slightly* more complex than that can get a *lot* more complex in a hurry.

Comment: I was just typing this up!  +1 for thinking like me <grin>

Comment: @cciotti: It's all **superficially** very easy ... BUT: need to examine the `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels` stream in case the user has shuffled the sheet order; `<v>` element for text cells give you an index into the `xl/sharedStrings.xml` stream; got dates in your data? You might want to look in the `xl/styles.xml` stream and decode the `num_format_str` to tell whether your floats are dates or numbers and look in the `xl/workbook.xml` stream for date epoch (1900 or 1904) plus other maybe-useful workbook-level info; `_xdead__xbeef_`-style escaping of not-valid-XML characters.

Comment: very exciting to see the hidden zip file wearing the mask of *.xlsx file. Wow!

Comment: Is it the same for Excel 2010?

Answer (score 3):

You have several choices:
1) Save your excel worksheet to a csv file and parse that.
2) Use the COM API (Windows proprietary and tricky)
3) [See this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/BasicExcel.aspx) for a C++ class that you could modify.

Comment: 4) pure python solution :) http://juno-devel.ovh.org/Public/Code/Python/xls2csv.0.4.py - only depends on the package "xlrd"

Comment: The linked C++ class only appears to work for the older `.xls` format, not the Excel 2007 `.xlsx` format. There's little similarity between the formats.

Comment: @Marco Mariani: The OP wants to read Excel data into memory; he doesn't want to butcher it and write it to a pseudo-CSV file. He should use `xlrd` directly [if he's happy with Python instead of C, and happy with using alpha code for reading XLSX files].

Answer (score 3):

Another C lib to read data from excel files can be found [here](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/).