# Assign values to variables in c file by reading excel sheet

Tags: c++, excel, file-handling

I need to assign values to variables in C file by reading an excel sheet. I have written a code but only the last variable has been assigned a value since I have used for loop.It is overwriting the values assigned to the previous variables as I am creating a different output file after assigning values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s1, s2, s3,s4;
string filename, text, line;
string cfilename,funcname, signal, value;

  int i , k , m;
cout << "Enter excel filename" << endl;
cin >> filename;
cout << "How many lines of text are in the file?" << endl;
cin >> m;
fstream file(filename);
if (!file) {
           cerr << "No such file exists." << endl;
           exit(1);
            }
if (file.is_open()) {

         while (file.eof()==0){

           for (k = 0; k < m; k++)  {                               //Loops for as many lines as there are in the file

                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                           //Loops for each comma-separated word in the line


                   if (i == 0){
                        getline(file, text, ',');           
                        cfilename=text;
                   cout << cfilename << '\t';}

                   else if (i == 1){
                         getline(file, text, ',');
                         funcname=text;
                   cout << funcname << '\t';}

                   else if (i == 2){
                         getline(file, text, ',');
                         signal=text;
                   cout << signal << '\t';}

                   else if (i == 3){
                        getline(file, text, '\n');
                        value=text;
                   cout << value << '\n';}

                                         }

                                    string s1=signal,s2=value;          

                                    s2 = s2 + ";  //";

                                    int offset, inset;

                                    string line;

                                    string search=s1;

                                    fstream cfile(cfilename);

                                    fstream fileOutput;

                                    fileOutput.open("output.c");

                                    if(cfile.is_open() && fileOutput.is_open()) {


                                                                        while(!cfile.eof()) {

                                                                            getline(cfile, line);

                                                                            if ((offset = line.find(funcname)) != string::npos){

                                                                                        cout << "found: " << funcname << endl;                      

                                                                                        string line1;

                                                                                        fileOutput << line << '\n';

                                                                                        skip:

                                                                                        while(getline(cfile,line1)){


                                                                                            if((inset=line1.find(search, 0)) !=string::npos){

                                                                                                cout<<"found: " << search << endl;

                                                                                                string s3 = s1+ "=" +s2;

                                                                                                //cout<<s3;

                                                                                                line1.replace( inset, inset+s1.size(), s3 );}


                                                                                            fileOutput << line1 << '\n';

                                                                                            goto skip;

                                                                                            }   

                                                                                        getchar();  }

                                                                            fileOutput << line << '\n'; }

                                                                    cfile.close();
                                                                    fileOutput.close();
                                                                     }
                                        }
                                  }
                            }
                    file.close();
                    getchar();
                    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to search a function first and then variables inside that function.

Need some help here.

Comment: Looks like already answered in the post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230706/read-from-excel-file-in-c

Comment: Actually i  have problem in assigning the values to variables in c file. The above link deals with reading the values from excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's this the problem but... I thing the `while ()` is too much.

when you have readed the `m` lines of the file, your

```
while (file.eof()==0)
```

result true because you haven't read nothing past the end of file.

So you read other `m` lines (failing but without controls about the success of the reading).

EDIT: I think you should write something like

```
cout << "Enter excel filename" << endl;
cin >> filename;
fstream file(filename);
if (!file) {
   cerr << "No such file exists." << endl;
   exit(1);
}
while (   getline(file, cfilename, ',') && getline(file, funcname, ',') 
       && getline(file, signal, ',') && getline(file, value, '\n')) {
   cout << cfilename << '\t' << funcname << '\t' << signal << '\t'
      << value << '\n';

   string s1=signal,s2=value;  
   [...]
```

Comment: I did the change but the output is exactly the same as before. Can u tell me how to avoid writing the whole output file for each line in csv? I just want to continue from the point where i replace the string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What you want to do is just eleborare the first row of the csv file?

Comment: No. My csv file contains different variables and its  corresponding values in each line. I wanna search for the variables and their values and write it to the output file so that variables in output file has values. But my code above overwrites whole output file for 1 line in csv file i.e, only 1 variable is assigned the value. but i want all the values to be assigned to the variables. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

The program does exactly what you asked it to do:

- you read a CSV file (excel format is binary!) line by line
- for each line in csv:

  - you **erase** the output file because you open a fstream without specifying `ios::ate`
  - search something in a source file and write to the output file.

As you erase the output file at every new line from the input CSV file, you cannot get more than the last operation.

It would be much simpler if you opened the output file once outside of the loop.

And... `while (file.eof() == 0)` is an anti-pattern. You look whether you have reached end of file **before** trying to read a line, and then read 4 values when the first getline have set the eof flag. You must test for eof immediately after a read and not before...

Comment: Ya thats the problem iam facing. Can u plz tell me how to avoid rewriting the whole file for each line in csv in the above code. Also, i tried using ios::ate in the above code, but not working, How can i do that?

Comment: And when i try to create the output file with fstream, it doesn't create and write to the file. I'll have to create the file using ofstream which creates the output file but doesn't write anything, and then change the command to fstream in the next execution to write to the file. Any solution for this?